# Why does VBA give an error when pasting a certain formula, but not when pasting others?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to execute the following code in Excel/VBA:

```
Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("D54") = "=COUNTA($F$6:$F$51)"
Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("D55") = "=COUNTA($E$6:$E$51)"
Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("M52") = "=SUM($M$6:$M$51)"
Worksheets("Portfolio").Range("L52") = "=SUMPRODUCT($I$6:$I$51;$L$6:$L$51)/SUM($I$6:$I$51)"
```

When done, the three first ones execute as expected, but the last one gives the error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I don't see why this is. The formula works fine when manually entered, and even if it weren't, it shouldn't break the code, right?

I've tried to fix it by breaking up the line, assigning the formula to a variable, tested if it works if another formula is substituted (it does), and reordering. Nothing helps.

Comment: Type the formula you want manually into your version of Excel - how does it want it formatted? Note that you use a semi-colon above, but depending on the language settings of your Excel, it may want a comma instead. See how it formats when you type it into the formula bar.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Thank you for your suggestion. The formula works just as expected when inputted manually.

Comment: macro record yourself putting the formula in, then can you post that code?

Comment: @99moorem That worked! VBA wanted the following code: `Range("L52").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(R6C9:R51C9,R6C12:R51C12)/SUM(R6C9:R51C9)"`

Comment: @Viele Glad to hear its working now. I have put that in my answer below just for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Semi colon used rather than colon

```
"=SUMPRODUCT($I$6:$I$51;$L$6:$L$51)/SUM($I$6:$I$51)"
```

See below with fixed colon

```
"=SUMPRODUCT($I$6:$I$51:$L$6:$L$51)/SUM($I$6:$I$51)"
```

After further investigation below is the correct formula

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(R6C9:R51C9,R6C12:R51C12)/SUM(R6C9:R51C9)"
```

Comment: Interestingly, this fixes the execution problem. However, it makes the formula incorrect. To my knowledge the SUMPRODUCT formula is written correctly.

Comment: I believe the semi-colon is likely meant to be a comma, not a colon; I don't believe you can use colons over multiple ranges like that within the sumproduct formula.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I tried substituting a comma into the function manually, and it broke it. It should be a semi-colon.

Comment: This might not make any sense but give it a try. Try building the string like this.   "=SUMPRODUCT($I$6:$I$51" & ";" & "$L$6:$L$51)/SUM($I$6:$I$51)"

Comment: That is interesting. I just tried your [@Viele's] formula above in mine, and it worked - though due to my language settings I needed a comma. Does anyone know if it's possible for the language settings of the VBA module to be different than the Excel workbook itself? Maybe one wants a comma and the other wants a semi-colon, and it won't accept it?

Comment: See the original post for a solution. @MatthewD that was a nice idea but unfortunately it gave the same error. VBA seems to have input something extra to the function that I don't understand.

Comment: I was mostly interested in whether it was me who had done something wrong and I wanted to understand that if so, but I'm concluding that it was just Excel/language settings that bugged up a bit.

Comment: I believe VBA is always US English (dates, commas, etc). But you should be able to use the `FormulaLocal` property to pass it a string with delimiters that are proper to your language.